# How do I alphabetize comma-separated values in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, alphabetized

I have a dataframe in R as shown in the first table below. I would like to alphabetize the comma-separated values within each cell for specified columns (Q1, Q2, etc) so that it results in a dataframe as shown in the second table below.

| id | Q1 | Q2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | alpha,charlie,apple | B,D,C,A |
| 2 | zulu,delta,bravo | D,A,C,B |

| id | Q1 | Q2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | alpha,apple,charlie | A,B,C,D |
| 2 | bravo,delta,zulu | A,B,C,D |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could split both the columns, do the `sort`ing and then `paste` back

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(across(c(Q1, Q2), ~ map_chr(strsplit(., ","), ~ toString(sort(.x)))))
```

-output

```
id                    Q1         Q2
1  1 alpha, apple, charlie A, B, C, D
2  2    bravo, delta, zulu A, B, C, D
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:2, Q1 = c("alpha,charlie,apple", "zulu,delta,bravo"
), Q2 = c("B,D,C,A", "D,A,C,B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```